# How to run Github code (with python) automatically on MyBinder or Google Colab without downloading the Sample code?

Tags: python, github

**MyBinder** and **Colaboratory** are feasible to allow people to run our examples from the website directly in their browser, without any download required.

When I work on the Binder, our data to be loaded takes a huge time. So, I need to run python code on the website directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I totally get the question. If you want to avoid having to download the data from another source, you can add the data into you git repo which you use to start Binder. It should look something like this: https://github.com/lschmiddey/book_recommender_voila

However, if your dataset is too big to be uploaded to your git repo, you have to get the data onto the provided Binder server somehow. So you usually have to download the data onto your Binder Server so that other users can work on your notebook.